# Which one is the frame number?

Tags: serial-number

I have two numbers under my frame, can you help me understand which one is the frame number? Is it the same thing as serial number? And what is the other one? The make of the bike is Leader Fox, the two serial numbers I can read are
DA2019292 and M1301617 (or MI301617 )

[image]

I want to register the bike on the website that helps in case it's stolen. Also, police would need this number too. So I only need some number that is unique within this bike model.

Comment: Serial numbers on bicycles are not like those on cars, they are not unique, except maybe for the maker, there is no world-wide database and no pattern for encoding. The number may only be relevant if you want to register the bike with the maker's website where they will tell you which of the two is required.

Comment: Have you tried calling the company and what are you trying to gain from decoding the serial number?

Comment: @carel is right - you should consider registering the bike wiht the manufacturer too, for warranty purposes if nothing else.

Comment: Register three times the bicycle, one bicycle with the top number, one with the bottom, one with both.

You did a good job in taking a screenshot of your codes as well, I will edit your question copying the serial numbers so internet will almost always find them ;)

Answer (score 4):

You will need to contact Leader Fox to answer this question.
The Leader Fox website does not have any information on which of those numbers is the bicycle serial number.

Here is a [link to the manuals](https://www.leaderfox.cz/en/guides) for their bikes.
Their manuals do contain information on the serial number for the motors on their e-bike which is not the same thing as the serial number for the whole bike.
Here is a [link to their contact page](https://www.leaderfox.cz/en/kontakty)

Comment: Good point about parts having different serial numbers to the whole bike.  In this case both numbers are stamped into the frame under the BB.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that when you register your bike, put **both** numbers/strings into the system.

If you only put one, then some day when its been recovered after a theft, the operator might put the other number in, and not score a match.

**Whichever is the correct serial number doesn't really matter in this specific case.**

If some other bike duplicates one block of text, then the description (colour/size/etc)  and the other number will help differentiate them.

Good work with pre-registering your bike before there's any incident.  Its too late once the bike's been pinched.